# Can we solve $KQK^*=I$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

Can we solve the following matrix equation in $K$

$$KQK^*=I$$

where $Q$ is non-singular and $I$ is the identity matrix, using SDP and LMI constraints?

Comment: Consider posting your thoughts and efforts in this (and future) posts.

Comment: if $Q = P D P^*$ where $D$ is real diagonal and non singular, then the solution is $K = D^{-1/2} P^*$. that there is no other solution is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem . so in the general case (if you have constraints) you should probably accept to minimize $||K Q K^* - I||_F^2$ instead of requiring $||K Q K^* - I||_F^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Nonlinear equality constraints are not convex, so there is no way to represent this using LMIs. Consider the $n=1$ case, $k^2q=1$; its solution set is $k=\pm 1/\sqrt{q}$.